# Change module route in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, routes

I've got module `admin`. Normally in ZF creates route for this module under it's name, but I don't want this behaviour.

I'd like to access `admin` module under another route, for example `totallyNotAdminPanel` and I want it to be the ONLY possible route to access this module BUT I'd like view url helper to point to this module when I'll call `$this->url(['module'=>'admin']);`

---

Conclusion:

- `admin` module must be accessed only by `totallyNotAdminPanel` route
- URL view helper must point to `totallyNotAdminPanel` route, although `['module' => 'admin']` param is passed.

Is there any way to achieve it in ZF1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use custom route for that.

I would do it like that:

1. Create custom route and initialize it in bootstrap class. e.g.

   ```
   public function _initRoutes () {
       $router = $this->_front->getRouter();
       $router->addRoute(
          'admin-panel',
           new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
               'totallyNotAdminPanel/:controller/:action/*',
               ['module' => 'admin']
           )
       );
   }
   ```
2. In the view use custom url to create links e.g.

   ```
   $this->url(['module'=>'admin', 'controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'list'], 'admin-panel');
   ```

Which will give you output like: /totallyNotAdminPanel/users/list

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately this does not work properly. When I'm linking to default module from admin module with changed route, I get url like this: `/notAdminPanel/home/index/module/default`

Comment: I bypassed the problem by adding 'default' route in controller.
Thank you for your help! :)